# How to pad a irregular shape tensor in tensorflow with pure TF way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

```
test_tensor = [[2], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5]] # irregular shape
# dose there have a tf (better, and faster?) function to pad this tensor to a dense tensor with a defult value?
# like this: test_tensor ==> dense tensor:[[2, -1, -1],[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, -1]]
```

Ps. Please do not use pure python & numpy

**Because I need add this operation into my TF model graph, so maybe need complete the operation with pure TF way?**